# Does MAC replace CSMA/CD in Ethernet?

Tags: ethernet, networking, mac

We now that in old days Ethernet use CSMA/CD for collision domain. However, with the advent of Switches now MAC addresses are used to identify the source and destination machine. But still when I read about Ethernet protocol it says it use CSMA/CD for collision domain. Even though we can clearly see the use of source and destination MAC address in the Ethernet packet. Is the MAC use with the help of switches to avoid collision domain is the part of newer standard of Ethernet and replace the older CSMA/CD or there is something else?

How MAC is related to Ethernet is it a part of Ethernet standard?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two things are not related, and MAC addresses are required in both scenarios.

Ethernet was not only CSMA/CD but also a bus. Being a bus means that is connects more then two systems with each other. Each time you have a shared medium connecting more then two systems, you need to know which of these systems send the packet and to which of these systems this packet was sent. This is why any bus (or any other shared medium connecting more than two systems) needs addressing, and this is why there are MAC addresses in Ethernet header. Their primarily use is for receivers to determine whether the frame was sent to them or someone else.

Bridges were originally designed to connect several CSMA/CD buses together. That is each bus was interconnecting several systems, where one, two, or more of them could be bridges. If you see the STP specification, you can see examples with 3 bridges connected together with a LAN.

Bridges are transparent and do the same MAC learning procedure as you described. "Transparent" means that other systems connected to the bus do not know of them. The whole network with several buses and bridges is viewed by others as a single shared medium. As it is shared, frames need addresses. And since frames have addresses in the first place, transparent bridges use them.

Today, in Ethernet physical topology consists of switches (or bridges) interconnected by point-to-point links, not buses. However, switches/bridges are still transparent and are still viewed as a big shared medium by other systems. Which means they still need addresses for the same purpose as original Ethernet bus.

P.S. Ethernet standard specifies frame format, which contains header fields for source and destination MAC addresses. See e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame#Structure). This is more or less the only thing that have not changed since the original CSMA/CD Ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

MAC addresses have been used for Ethernet's data link layer addressing from the very start.

Repeaters simply copied all incoming frames (actually just the bits) to all ports but the ingress one, and then the end nodes' NICs sorted out all the garbage they didn't need. Switches learn the network's MAC address distribution and only forward frames to the desired port.

Another switch feature is the buffering and potentially queueing of frames. That way, a switch can receive a frame from a source even if the destination port is currently busy. That way, each port can receive and transmit simultaneously, removing the need for cumbersome bus arbitration - CSMA/CD.

Of course, CSMA/CD and half-duplex mode are things of the past which are only supported on largely obsolete 10 and 100 Mbit/s links.

You can find all about CSMA/CD's media access control in IEEE 802.3 clauses 2/9/13, 27, and 41 for 10/100/1000 Mbit/s respectively - note that a half-duplex mode was defined for Gigabit Ethernet but it isn't supported anywhere. Faster Ethernet variants are full duplex in general.